# Why do we use "error quaternions" for control of attitude?

Tags: control-systems

I'm working on an attitude control system in terms of quaternions, and i'm basing my approach on the book [Space Vehicle Dynamics and Control (2nd ed.)](https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/book/10.2514/4.860119).  If we consider a proportionate controller, i.e.

$$\mathbf{u} = -\mathbf{K}_p \mathbf{q}_e $$

it would seem logical to me to define the error quaternions to be the first three elements of

$$\begin{bmatrix}
  q_{1e} \\
  q_{2e} \\
  q_{3e} \\
  q_{4e} \\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
  q_{1} \\
  q_{2} \\
  q_{3} \\
  q_{4} \\
\end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix}
  q_{1c} \\
  q_{2c} \\
  q_{3c} \\
  q_{4c} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Where $q_i$ are the actual quaternions and $q_c$ are the desired (commanded) quaternions. Yet in the book, they instead define

$$\begin{bmatrix}
  q_{1e} \\
  q_{2e} \\
  q_{3e} \\
  q_{4e} \\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
  q_{4c} & q_{3c} & -q_{2c} & -q_{1c}  \\
  -q_{3c} & q_{4c} & q_{1c} & -q_{2c} \\
  q_{2c} & -q_{1c} & q_{4c} & -q_{3c} \\
  q_{1c} & q_{2c} & q_{3c} & q_{4c}\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
  q_{1} \\
  q_{2} \\
  q_{3} \\
  q_{4} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

To me it seems like we do this because there are multiple possible quaternions that correspond to the same orientation, but I have not yet found a clear explanation for this. Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Page back in the book a bit to check the math, or do some cyphering.  As used in navigation, quaternions define rotations, and rotation is carried out by multiplying them together.  So I would expect that $q_e$ would be the solution to either $q_i q_e$ = $q_c$, or $q_e q_i$ = $q_c$.  If so, the matrix math is just how the actual numerical solution is calculated.

Comment: One reason : With Quaternions you can never get in gimbal lock.

Answer (score 1):

A possible explanation is that a set of 4 quaternions is not independent, so by converting them to error quaternions, we get 3 independent values that we can use to calculate 3 independent control actions (one for each axis).